# Why has my question been in review for over a week?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I've been blocked from asking questions for a little while now. I believe I've fixed all of my questions and have submitted them for review but it's been a week without it being declined or accepted.

Here is my question that's submitted for review:

[tkinter stringVar() not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69890599/tkinter-stringvar-not-defined/69905729#69905729)

Comment: Yeah, it's holiday season for a decent chunk of the planet. Reviews are going to take longer for a while. It's an unavoidable fact when there's volunteers involved, especially when there's normally too few people doing reviews (correctly), compared to what the volume of posts demands.

Comment: And while I'm at it, deleted questions, score <= 0, contributing to the [question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans): [1](//stackoverflow.com/q/69959295) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/67066788) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/65737789) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/65686231)

Comment: Why exactly does the question have to be reopened? It already has an answer that you have accepted. In fact I would argue the question is caused by a typo

Comment: @SecurityHound as you can see, the variables are registered and so are the keywords. It has to be reopen for my question ban to be lifted, right?

Comment: @Zoe those have been deleted as dont count, right?

Comment: Deleted questions do count, at least according to the little that has been made public about the ban system. That's also why the comment explicitly says "deleted questions [...] **contributing to the question ban**"

Comment: @richmail - **That question being reopened WILL NOT lift your question ban nor will deleting the question, in fact, deleting will require even more positively submitted questions.**  Which will be difficult since you can only submit a single question every 6 months.  You have way to many deleted questions, which likely are downvoted, which means you have to ask NEW questions that are receiveied positively

Answer (score 1):

The commenters have already pointed this out, but there's no guarantee that your question will be reviewed within a particular amount of time. Reviewing is done by volunteers in their free time, and this occurred during a major holiday for much of the world.

Your best bet is to make sure that you take the time to formulate the question well **before** you post it, and to be prompt in responding to any feedback you get on the question.